# How to get size of GZIPPED file in BYTES Java

Tags: java, gzip

I am passing a GZIPPED file through postman as a @RequestBody. I would like to know the size of this file, how can I do this in Java.

I tried this but it doesn't return the correct size:

```
public int testing(@RequestBody byte[] binary){
  return binary.size
}
```

Comment: Which size does it return? Too small, too large?

Comment: If you have the physical file can't you get file.length() which gets the size in bytes?

Comment: Are you after the compressed or the uncompressed size?

Comment: @OleV.V. I want the compressed file size, but I would prefer to have both. It returns the size too small

Answer (score -2):

I tried bytes.length and now it is returning the correct file size. Before it was returning a wrong number and I am not sure why it was doing that but now it is consistently returning the correct file size.

Comment: So you had a bug and you don't even know what it was. Please delete this futile question.

Comment: It is easy to spot a couple of bugs in the code; an array doesn’t have a `size` attribute, and there’s a semicolon missing. How the OP got a too small number out I cannot tell, but it has hardly been from the code in the question.